# What are the advantages of a group package in yum over an rpm that depends on everything else?

Tags: rpm, yum

On our local repository, we'd like to create a "product" install that includes all of our packages. The two ways that seem possible to do this is do create a "blank" package called 'product' that depends on all our other rpms. Or we can create a group package in yum that includes all of those rpms.

A quick google, I couldn't find a pro/con of either approach. Anyone have an opinion on either direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a **metapackage** means that all the packages it depends on *must* be installed, with no chance for customization of capabilities due to presence or absence of the various packages. This can be fixed by removing the metapackage before removing other packages, but users aren't always certain whether or not the metapackage can be removed safely.

A yum group allows all the packages to be installed at once, but also allows pick-and-choose without frustrating the end user. This can cause issues if a user installs only specific packages manually without installing enough for the application to be functional, but accurate interdependencies between the various application packages should make sure that a minimum set is installed when any of them are chosen.

Answer (score 0):

metapackage needs to use yum to install all the dependencies, if yum can't find one of the dependencies, metapackage can't be installed successfully.
a "product" install that includes all of our package, can be install by rpm command, we don't need to resolve dependencies for it.